# Can one traveller travel with TWO tickets and a Two Together Railcard?

Tags: uk, trains

Suppose two people have booked train tickets with a Two Together Railcard, but one can't make it.  Can the other person take BOTH tickets and proceed with travel?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no.

https://www.twotogether-railcard.co.uk/help/terms-conditions/

> 3. Both tickets must be bought together and both named cardholders must be travelling together to enable discounted tickets to be used.

However, you should be able to get a refund (perhaps with an admin fee) if you do it before when you would have travelled, or even perhaps a railcard-to-no-railcard excess, from a ticket office.

Comment: I hope so — see [this related question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/97792/2509) (that you've probably seen, putting it here for future reference)

Answer (score 1):

I just phoned with a person at First Transpennine Express, where I purchased the tickets.

The person on the phone advised me that, in spite of the text of the conditions of carriage, the one person still travelling should simply bring her ticket along with the railcard.  Upon ticket checks, the traveller should tell the conductor that her friend could not make it.  I was told that in this case, she will not be held liable to pay an excess penalty fare, as long as she can present her ticket and the railcard.

Comment: If you want to risk it, sure. Personally, if I didn't have it in writing, I wouldn't try. Rail staff have known to have given outrageously wrong oral advice in the past, and then it just turns into a "he said, she said". But because the evidence is against you - you were travelling with an invalid ticket - unless you have written proof, it's rather difficult to be sure.

Comment: @Muzer Maybe so.  Personally, my experience has been that train crew are usually lenient in their rules application; more than once I've used an Advance ticket on a later-than-indicated train and they've always let me proceed, despite the conditions stating I would have to buy a new full fare ticket.

Comment: indeed, I've also experienced similar leniency in the past (hell, a surprising number of times I've shown tickets that are obviously invalid by mistake and they didn't even notice), but sod's law states that the one time you're relying upon it is the one time they won't be ;)